# specify a point where to change from static to fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="content_to_stick"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

I am trying to make the .content_to_stick, to have position:fixed untill reaches the .footer but cant figure it out at all.
This is the **jQuery** i use:

```
 jQuery(function(){
    var stickyRibbonTop = jQuery('.content_to_stick').offset().top;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > jQuery('.footer').offset().top ) {  
                     jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});   
            } else {
                    jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            }
    });
    });
```

Comment: I'd look at doing this purely in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you reach the `.footer` `$(window).scrollTop()` is still bigger than `stickyRibbonTop` and your code will never get to the part where it sets `position` back to `static`. Try switch conditions

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > jQuery('.footer').offset().top) {
        jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
    } else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop) {  
        jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
    } else {
        jQuery('.content_to_stick').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
    }
});
```